# Excel VBA run on entry

Tags: vba, excel

Ive never written anything in VBA.  I have a scale that is weighing items and entering them into excel.  However, it takes a reading when I weigh something and then it also records a reading when the scale is empty between weighings.  Im trying to get rid of the empty reading in column D.  It really needs to happen on every entry into the spreadsheet.

This code works if I run it manually.  How do I wrap it so that it executes automatically?  Also, please be deliberate in explaining how to activate the code.  For whatever reason its not clear from my internet searches.

```
Sub clean_input_data()
Dim i As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

With ActiveSheet
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    i = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    If i < 2 Then
        MsgBox "No data found, macro exiting"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With .Range("D1:D" & i)
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<=0.005", Operator:=xlAnd
        End With
    End If
    .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks so much

Comment: "I have a scale that is weighing items and entering them into excel" - what exactly does this look like in practice?  What triggers a new entry, and where does each new entry get placed?

Comment: Probably by using the `Worksheet_Change` event, and adding some logic to ignore when the entry == 0 (or whatever an "empty" scale would register in the worksheet)

Comment: Tim.  I am running rs232 key software.  Its a "keyboard wedge" software.  It reads the incoming data from the serial port and puts it into the keyboard buffer.  The scale sends data when it senses a new weight and then stabilizes (hence it records loaded and unloaded).  The value gets entered into excel from the keyboard buffer with an "Enter" afterwards.  So in Excel the data is inputted by the rs232 software then it hits enter for me.  I want to delete the "unloaded" rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the following subroutine in the worksheet tab that contains the measurements:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target.Parent.Range("D:D"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Run "clean_input_data"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I just saw David's response now, I think he has a better idea.

Comment: If you are talking about my answer, the user just uses the subroutine that he has already found to work.  As for David's comment, you could have something like:  `TempRange=Intersect(Target.Parent.Range("D:D"), Target)` then `For Each Cell in TempRange` `If ABS(Cell.Value)<=0.005 then Cell.EntireRow.Delete` etc.

Comment: This seems to create some sort of endless loop with debug pointing at  ".AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<=0.005", Operator:=xlAnd"  .  The "clean_input_data" code executes fine without the worksheet_change call.  However, thats what I need to automate this.

Comment: Yes,  you're right.  Sorry about that, I forgot to add something to disable the events.  Please see the revised answer.

Comment: Ah. I see @Demetri. Sorry, I was thinking "wipe-out" the bad entry on the `Worksheet_Change` event. +1 for a nice-easy integration :)